# What is wrong with the restart game function in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The restart game function doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. The balloons, scores resets but the game doesn't resets, i can't shoot the balloons again. (plus the askUser,  yesBtn and noBtn doesn't go invisible either)

```
function createBalloons(a, b)
  for i = 1, a do
     for j = 1, b do

         local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 270+ (i * 30), 80 + (j * 50))
         balloonText = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+1], 300, 125)
         balloonTextt = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+2], 300, 175)
         balloonTexttt = display.newText(hiragana_array[x+3], 300, 225)
         balloonText:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloonTextt:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloonTexttt:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloon.name = 'balloon'
         physics.addBody(balloon)
         balloon.bodyType = 'static'
         table.insert(balloons, balloon)
         end
    end
    target.text = #balloons
end
    function restartLvl()  
        for i = 1, #balloons do
        display.remove(balloons[i])
        print ("restart level")
        end

        score.text = '0'
        ballRemain.text = '3'
        balloons = {}
        createBalloons(1, 3)
        askUser.isVisible = false
        yesBtn.isVisible = false
        noBtn.isVisible = false
        print("time from start: ", (system.getTimer()-gameTime))
        print('send mail')
        sendMail()

    end
```

This is what it shows in the simulator.
[image]

Comment: can you show createBalloons()? also, you mean that it doesn't respond after the last line of your stdout but until then it responded fine after 3rd restart level printed?

Comment: the askUser, uesBtn and noBtn.isVisible doesn't work for some reason

Comment: perhaps you paused physics and/or removed ontouch-handler when game finished, and didn't start physics in restartLvl?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any problem with that code, my guess is the problem is elsewhere. You're going to have to dig a little more, maybe put some more print statements. For example maybe `isVisible` is being reset to true by another function, after the `restartLvl`, like in an enterFrame handler.